# Расширение ORM Django

Tags: django-orm, postgresql, django

При разработке довольно простых на первый взгляд проектов у меня возникли задачи, кторорые не получилось решить стандартными средствами ORM Django. В принципе, они похожи, но подразумевают различные решения.

1) Хранение списков. PostgreSQL предоставляет возможность хранения списков, но такой возможности не предоставляет Django ORМ.

2) Хранение питоновских объектов. В принципе, при помощи JSON или XML в текстовых полях можно хранить вообще всё, что угодно. Вопрос только в том, как расширить TextField так, чтобы питоновский объект конвертировался в JSON для хранения и из JSON'a для использования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для п.2 посмотрите JSONField и PickleField. Возможно, для п.1 тоже батарейка есть.

Comment: Да в том-то и дело, что я не хотел бы использовать сторонние батарейки для такого рода задач, по крайней мере для п.2. У меня простые объекты, у которых всего 3 активных числа и поиск по этим объектам не подразумевается. Не думаю, что это стоит установки такой батарейки.

Comment: да там батареечка не большая https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield . Ну скопипасть код к себе в проект если принципиально не хочется пакет ставить https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-jsonfield/src/47f9455c910a431cab21f2932b7e0fbb2473bd75/jsonfield/?at=default

Comment: Неужели, чтобы хранить в JSON объект, описание которого занимает 30 строк необходимо копипастить 500?

Comment: Вы хотите вместо использования готовой (даже с тестами!) библиотеки городить свой велосипед. Ваше право, но зачем тогда спрашивать, как лучше? Сделайте getter и setter, протестируйте, вынесите отдельно и придумайте, как сделать их прозрачно работающими с разными полями, когда это потребуется в другой модели.

И да, копипастить Вам предложили, если Вам претит ставить дополнительную либу (что само по себе довольно странно).

Comment: 1) Использование сторонних библиотек не всегда оправдано.
2) Понимание работы Django ORM я считаю полезным навыком и хочу его приобрести, чтобы не зависеть от подобных библиотек. Не будет мне хватать их функционала, что тогда?
3) Мне не совсем понятен пример из стандартной документации Django, поэтому я и обратился сюда за помощью.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите исходники предложенной Вам либы, там все понятно и по делу.